# MongoDB equivalent of "NOT BETWEEN"

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB, the PHP driver, and Google Maps. Since Google Maps does a wrap-around for Longitudes (the LEFT longitude could be greater than the RIGHT longitude in some cases), I'm trying to get the equivalent of MySQL's **NOT BETWEEN** working in MongoDB.

Has anyone successfully used the MongoDB "$or" operator to simulate NOT BETWEEN?

Here's my (unsuccessful) attempt so far:

```
// If the LEFT longitude is greater
if ($longitude_left > $longitude_right) {
    $params = array(
        '$or' => array(
            'longitude' => array('$gte' => $longitude_left, '$lte' => $longitude_right)
        )
    );
}
// By default, the RIGHT longitude is greater
else {
    $params = array(
        'longitude' => array(
            '$gte' => $longitude_left, '$lte' => $longitude_right
        )
    );
}

$mongo = new Mongo();
$cursor = $mongo->energy->plants->find($params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB's PHP driver always accepts/expects arrays ...

Since you are passing arrays for **$gte** and **$lte** too ... *both* need to be in arrays for **$or** to work correctly.

In your example you pass the first part in an array but not an array for **$or** and 2 more arrays for **$gte** and **$lte** ...

For your example to work, you'll need to do something like ...

```
$params = array('$or' => array(
                     array('longitude' => array('$gte' => $longitude_left)),
                     array('longitude' => array('$lte' => $longitude_left))
                   )
           );

$cursor = $collection->find($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NOT BETWEEN (a, b)
```

basically translates into

into an $or clause with

```
$lt a
$gt b
```

Converting this into a MongoDB JSON query syntax is straight forward. Or where is your problem?